# barchart stacked within groups in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to somehow make a stacked within groups barplot with a way to customize the colors and patterns. I can do these two things separately but am having some difficulty when trying to use `patternbar_s()`  with `facet_grid()` in the same plot.

I can create a stacked within groups barplot in example 1 and a stacked with customizable bars in example 2.

want end result to look like:

#Example 1 stacked within groups barplot

```
set.seed(687532)                     # Create example data frame
data <- data.frame(facet = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 6),
                   group = c("x", "y"),
                   stack = letters[1:3],
                   value = round(abs(rnorm(30)), 2))
data  

ggplot(data,                         # Draw barplot with grouping & stacking
       aes(x = group,
           y = value,
           fill = stack)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "stack") +
  facet_grid(~ facet, switch = "both") +
  theme_classic() + theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = NA, fill=NA, size=0),
                          text = element_text(size = 8, family = "sans"),
  ) + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

output
[image]
#Example 2 patterns and gridlines

```
library(patternplot)
library(png)
library(ggplot2)
data <- read.csv(system.file("extdata", "monthlyexp.csv", package="patternplot"))
x<-data$Location
y<-data$Amount
group<-data$Type
data

patternbar_s(data,data$Location, data$Amount, data$Type,xlab='', ylab='Monthly Expenses, Dollar', label.size=3.5,
             pattern.type=c('crosshatch', 'nwlines', 'nwlines'),pattern.line.size=c(10, 5, 5),frame.size=1,
             pattern.color=c('darkgrey', 'grey', 'white'),background.color=c('white', 'white', 'black'),pixel=20, 
             density=c(10, 10, 10),frame.color='black', legend.type='h', legend.h=10, legend.y.pos=0.49,
             legend.pixel=10, legend.w=0.25, legend.x.pos=1.1, 
             legend.label=c("Childcare", "Food", "Housing" ))+scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6800)) +theme_classic()
```

output [image]

Comment: ah so basically, you're wanting to remove the borders from each of the five plots, to make them seem like they're one plot?